# найти все id в массиве с правильными ответами

Tags: javascript, node.js

Мне нужно получить массив правильных ответов, чтобы сравнить в тестах эти ответы и вывести сколько пользователь из тестов ответил на вопросов.
То есть мне нужно найти значение и получить их id.
Кстати бд я использую mysql
Как я реализовал

```js
router.get('/testing/:id', async ctx => {
        let answearArr = [];
        let test = await Test.test(ctx.params.id); // выводит все вопросы по данной теме
// получаю список ответов где хранится правильный или нет
        for(i=0; i < test.length; i++){
            let answear = test[i].id;
            answearArr.push(await Test.answear(answear));
        }
// пытаюсь получить з массива id правильных ответов на вопросы
        for(i=0; i < answearArr.length; i++){
            let arr = answearArr[i];
            console.log(arr.find({answer: 0}))
        }
    })
```

В итоге что я получаю

```
[ [ RowDataPacket { id: 1, text: 'один-два дня', id_question: 1, answer: 1 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 2, text: 'более 5 дней', id_question: 1, answer: 0 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 3, text: '3-5 дней', id_question: 1, answer: 0 } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { id: 4, text: 'да', id_question: 2, answer: 1 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 5, text: 'нет', id_question: 2, answer: 0 },
    RowDataPacket {
      id: 6,
      text: 'не постоянно, Меняется постоянно',
      id_question: 2,
      answer: 0 } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { id: 7, text: 'да', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 8, text: 'нет', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 9, text: 'не помню', id_question: 4, answer: 1 } ] ]
```

ключ answer - это ответы верный =1, 0= неверный.
Поэтому я попробовал сделать так

```
for(i=0; i < answearArr.length; i++){
            let arr = answearArr[i];
            console.log(arr.find({answer: 0}))
        }
```

Но получил ошибку

```
TypeError: # is not a function
```

Не пойму как можно еще получить массив правильных ответов. Или как можно еще раз рассмотреть данный решение в тестирование

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ для каждого вопроса:

```
allAnswers.forEach(function(answersForOneQ) {
  console.log(answersForOneQ.find(function(answer){ return answer.answer == 1; }));
});
```

Все правильные ответы:

```
console.log(allAnswers.map(function(answersForOneQ){ return answersForOneQ.find(
  function(answer){ return answer.answer == 1; }
)}));
```

Comment: У меня так не работает, пишет ошибку   TypeError: answersForOneQ.find is not a function